# New to rails... How do I set and call specific anchor points for a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor, single-page-application, link-to

So I want to create a single page portfolio, and I want to set anchor points so users can click on the nav bar and it jumps to the specific section of the page. So far I have this to set my anchor point:

```
<%= link_to "Code Snippets", anchor: "code_snippets" %>
<%= link_to "See My Web Apps", anchor: "web_apps" %>
<%= link_to "Contact Me", anchor: "contact" %>
<%= link_to "Resume", anchor: "Resume" %>
```

I dont know if this is the right syntax, but this is what I have found online so far...

Now, how do I call these anchor points, so my page jumps to the relevant information when the user clicks the link? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the html below to jump to the anchor point when you click.

```
<a name="Results"></a>
```

or

```
<div id="Results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so if the url for this:

```
<%= link_to "Code Snippets", anchor: "code_snippets" %>
```

is /code_snippets

you would hit this url

```
/code_snippets#my_anchor
```